# Chrome extensions disable web security

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension

I write chrome extension. When user go to page http://foo.com/ i load content script.
foo.com code like this:

```
<iframe src="http://bar.com/" id="bar"></iframe>
```

An i need in extension access to iframe content:

```
document.getElementById('bar').contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

When I run chrome with flag disable-web-security it works, but when chrome is running without this flag code don't work.

Is possible run chrome without flag disable web security and disable web security only for extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at the problem from the wrong angle. You just need to inject a content script into the `iframe` itself to access its contents.

For that, you will need [`"all_frames" : true` property](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#all_frames) of the content script.

Comment: I don't need insert content script to all frames. For example I need copy html from iframe to textarea in main document.

Comment: This is, however, the only way to do it without clobbering security completely. You need a separate copy of the content script in the frame you wish to access.